# python split string and get words after some character

Tags: python, split

hi I am using python and I need to know how can I split a string like this :

"sometext@aaaa sometext @bbbb sometext@cccc"

to an array lik this :

['aaaa','bbbb','cccc']

Comment: Apart from not showing any effort and/or clearly explaining what the specific problem is: you cannot do that. An array can hold anything, but you can't split up a string and end up with *variables* with the name of their contents.

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a we-write-your-code forum. Please provide the code you've tried or read a beginners tutorial.

Comment: @RadLexus I think he's still a beginner and has never done some programming before, so he might not know what strings are and that they're quoted.

Comment: Do you _really_ want `[aaaa,bbbb,cccc]`, or do you want `['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']`?  Is there supposed to be a space in `sometext @bbbb`?

Comment: @linusg: and therefore asking what strings are on SO is okay? It is not. Also, there is no problem with answering beginners' questions here, as long as they are good questions.

Comment: @RadLexus  I want to split "reply mentions" in comments and my problem solved by AKS answer

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, of course beginner questions are oky, but before starting coding, you should get the basics of the language. Also, this isn't a good question, see the definition in the Help center! Seems to be homework or something...

Comment: @PM2Ring yes sorry for my bad question. I want ['aaaa,'bbbb','cccc']

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Next time, you should post some relevant  code with your question. That shows us that you tried to solve the problem yourself, but more importantly (IMHO) by seeing what you're doing wrong we can explain why it's wrong and how to do it right. Often, problems in beginner code are due to fundamental misunderstandings about how Python works. A good answer doesn't just solve the immediate problem it also corrects those  misunderstandings.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks for your suggestion. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'@(\w+)', "sometext@aaaa sometext @bbbb sometext@cccc")
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

Comment: Why the downvote?? +1 for this working short answer!

Comment: I would like to know as well.

Comment: thanks it works! I tested some regex but they didn't work because I am not good in regular expressions. I will accept your response in minutes.

Comment: this regex cant detect id's with dot character like @aaa.aa .to do that I used \S instead of \w

Comment: That's great. I only used `\w` because using `\S` wan't required considering the example in the question.